# Dates in iPhone Settings Bundle

Tags: iphone, date, settings

I'm working on a very simple iPhone app, that in the end will have maybe 3 or 4 settings.

Ideally I'd like to use the Settings app provided for free in the SDK.

One of the settings I'd like the user to be able to enter is their date of birth, however [there doesn't seem to be a way](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Introduction/Introduction.html) to prompt the user for a date in the Settings app.

Aside from writing a custom settings page within my app, is there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way using the default settings is to use one or more textfields, and to parse the user's input to build a NSDate object.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`UIPickerView`](http://iappdevs.com/uipickerview-example.jsp) to allow the user to "dial in" values that correspond to a day, month, and year.

**EDIT**: Okay, thanks for clarifying. Perhaps take a look at the `PSMultiValueSpecifier` key and use its multi-value selectors for day, month and year selections.

Look at the tutorial section of the [Application Preferences](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH13) document for help on this, specifically the "Experience Level" portion.

Comment: What I'm after is a way to display one of those in the Settings system application.